# How to write prometheus alert rules for mesos and HAProxy process down.?

Tags: haproxy, mesos, prometheus

I am working on a task where I need to configure and validate prometheus alertmanager.User should get alert when mesos process and HAProxy process is down, I tried to find alert rules for these on internet, but did not find proper. Can any one tell me how to write the alert rules for these. basically need condition clause.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on how you are monitoring things. Let's use HAProxy as an example and say you are using the HAProxy Exporter (https://github.com/prometheus/haproxy_exporter) to monitor it. The HAProxy Exporter includes a metric named `haproxy_up`, which indicates whether it successfully scraped HAProxy (when Prometheus in turn scraped the exporter). If HAProxy couldn't be scraped, `haproxy_up` will have a value of `0` and you can alert on that. Let's say your HAProxy Exporter has a Prometheus job name of `haproxy-exporter`. You could then write an alerting rule like this:

```
ALERT HAProxyDown
  IF haproxy_up{job="haproxy-exporter"} == 0
  FOR 5m
  LABELS {
    severity = "page"
  }
  ANNOTATIONS {
    summary = "HAProxy {{ $labels.instance }} down",
    description = "HAProxy {{ $labels.instance }} could not be scraped."
  }
```

This will send an alert if any HAProxy instance could not be scraped for more than 5 minutes.

If you wanted to know whether the *exporter* (instead of HAProxy itself) was down, you could instead use the expression `up{job="haproxy-exporter"} == 0` to find any down HAProxy Exporter instances. Probably you'll want to check both actually.

I can't say much about Mesos and its exporter since I don't have any experience with them, but I imagine it would be something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Also for export mesos metrics you should use mesos-exporter. https://github.com/prometheus-junkyard/mesos_exporter
https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/mesos-exporter/
It also has mesos_up metric. Your alert should be the same like HaProxy alert:

```
ALERT MesosMasterDown
  IF mesos_up{job="mesos-master-exporter"} == 0
  FOR 5m
  LABELS {
    severity = "page"
  }
  ANNOTATIONS {
    summary = "Mesos master {{ $labels.instance }} down",
    description = "Mesos master {{ $labels.instance }} could not be scraped."
  }

ALERT MesosSlaveDown
  IF mesos_up{job="mesos-slave-exporter"} == 0
  FOR 5m
  LABELS {
    severity = "page"
  }
  ANNOTATIONS {
    summary = "Mesos slave {{ $labels.instance }} down",
    description = "Mesos slave {{ $labels.instance }} could not be scraped."
  }
```